# Javascript post data order

Tags: javascript, post, hash

I've got a bit of a funny problem that i'm sure others here will find easy to solve.  I need to hash an entire query string, then include that hash value in the post data.

After trying it a few other ways, i'm trying to do this with javascript. Somehow it seems like the order in which the string is pulled together from the form to be hashed differs from the way that it is pulled together when it is submitted.

I'm excluding a hidden element with a specific class to build up the query string to be hashed, then setting that hidden element with the hash value before the final submit.

Any idea what i might be doing wrong, or how i could ensure the order of elements is the same both on building the string and the submit?

The relevant snippet:

```
var allFormDat = document.getElementById("frmPayment").elements;
var hashingString ='';
var hashVal;
for (i=0;i<allFormDat.length;i++) {
    if (allFormDat[i].className!="nohash"){
        hashingString+=allFormDat[i].name+'='+allFormDat[i].value+'&';
    }
} 
hashingString.substring(0, hashingString.length - 1);
hashingString += '[salt]';

hashVal=SHA1(hashingString);
frm.hashValue.value=hashVal;

document.getElementById('frmPayment').submit();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what (confusing) results you're seeing? Also, while you're at it, you could easily add a check in the loop so that `if (i === length - 1)` you don't append the `&`; that way you don't have to strip it from the string when you're done.

Comment: Sure -- two major things, i guess. When i dump the post data, the hash value is in the middle of the string (while the hidden element is at the very end of the form submitted), and the hash value doesn't match up when i take this data and sha1 it externally..

Comment: Ach, thanks for the idea on the check. That felt awfully kludgy..

Comment: Sure; it popped out because I've done things like that more than once myself. You say "when you dump the post data"—presumably you mean on the back end, not somewhere in the Javascript here? Have you done a quick dump of the string after the `for` loop, using e.g. `alert()`? Iterating through the array as you are should give the expected result, but I'd start by confirming that it does.

Comment: It does indeed - both the hash value and the string cough up the expected result. There would be no reason that the post string would be assembled differently using  `document.getElementById('frmPayment').submit();` i suppose..?

Comment: That was going to be my next guess. In any case, if you're POSTing the data, you shouldn't need to access the whole POST string—you should be able to access the value with `$_POST['temp']`, right?

Comment: I think i follow you.. the difficulty is that it's a third party back-end, so presumably the POST data needs to be perfectly formed for it to work... otherwise this would be considerably easier to manage! I've contacted them to see if they can lend any further insight into why this is causing errors. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Oh, yuck. I'm rather curious how Javascript handles the serialization when it runs a `submit()` call. I should also note that the above was specific to PHP (blech; I've had that on my brain tonight), but regardless of the back end, they should be able to get the variable directly from the POST data; if they have to parse the string they're doing something wrong. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're not URI-encoding the components. You probably should:

```
var field = allFormDat[i];
hashingString += encodeURIComponent(field.name) + '='
               + encodeURIComponent(field.value) + '&';
```

`substring` does not work in-place. You'll have to reassign:

```
hashingString = hashingString.substring(0, hashingString.length - 1);
```